# Textfield being dequeued before textFieldDidEndEditing is called?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using a uitableview with a bunch of dynamically created custom cells each with a label and textfield similar to the settings app on the phone. Problem occurs when i have a lot of textfields say 20, the user selects the first textfield, changes its value then scrolls to the end of the table and selects the last textfield to edit. I get a EXEC_BAD_ACCESS in the textFieldDidEndEditing method because i think the textfield value is nil?? I think this might be happending because the 1st textfield that was being edited is being dequeued when the table is scrolled.  Everything works fine if you select textfields that are next to each other.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that one of the objects has been released before it gets that message. If it were set to nil, there would be no error. Make sure you're correctly retaining objects.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use editingChanged instead of the late arriving  textFieldDidEndEditing

That would work just about as well as the settings app does for the last few releases.